# How to select only <li> with a <ul>?

Tags: jquery, nested-lists

I have an `<li>` that contains another `<ul>` and `<li>`.

I want to be able to access either `<li>` and apply different functionality to each.

I've been going with the approach of:

*Example A:*

> If this `<li>` contains a `<ul>`, do this when clicking on the `<li>`.

*Example B:*

> If this `<li>` does not contain a `<ul>`, do this when clicking on the `<li>`.

It's not working though, so I'm trying to test the basics.

*Example A* seems to select both `<li>`'s, even the nested one that does not contain a `<ul>`.

*HTML*

```
<ul>
<li>i do have a ul - i should be green
<ul>
<li>i dont have a ul - i should be red</li>            
</ul>
</li>
<li>i dont have a ul - i should be red</li>
<li>i dont have a ul - i should be red</li>
</ul>
```

*jQuery*

```
// why does this first condition cause both li's to be green?

$("li:has(ul)").css('background','Green');

// uncomment the following and only one is green

//$("li:not(:has(ul))").css('background','Red');
```

*jsFiddle*

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/H5ZdE/2/

**Edit:**

Just to clarify, I am wanting to be specifically selective so that I can apply different click functionality to each `<li>`, so that is why I need to figure out how to select them accurately and not just rely on 'overiding' inherited styles etc.

Comment: It's not selecting both. The `<ul>` is in the `<li>`, so it also gets a green background.

Comment: because the child `li` inherits the background color from the ancestor element

Comment: Is there a way to specifically select each `<li>` rather than just 'override' the inherited style?  I've added clarification to the edit in original post.

Comment: how you ul, li select ? I think you should need radio button or drop down selection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

The following achieves the desired results ie separate functionality for top level and nested `<li>`'s.

To be honest I don't yet really know how it works, but it works and I added a bit of extra functionality to test things out.  But no marks needed for code prettiness.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<ul class="squares">
<li>
<ul class="nested">
<li class="hidden_li" style="height: 20px; width: 50px; background: yellow; display: none; position: relative; z-index: 999999; left: 0px;top: 70px;">
<a href="">test</a>
</li></ul>
</li>
<li>
<ul class="nested">
<li class="hidden_li" style="height: 20px; width: 50px; background: yellow; display: none; position: relative; z-index: 999999; left: 0px;top: 70px;">
<a href="">test</a>
</li></ul>
</li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
// etc
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
height: 205px;
overflow-y: auto;
width: 400px;
}

.select {
border: 2px solid red !important;
}

.select_blue {
border: 2px solid blue !important;
}

.squares {
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
white-space:nowrap;
}

#container ul li {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
border-radius: 4px;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
height: 100px;
margin-right: 25px;
vertical-align: top;
width: 100px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
// just for <li>
$(document).on("click","ul.squares > li:nth-child(1n-7)", function (e) {
$(".hidden_li").hide();    
$(this).find(".hidden_li").fadeIn();
$("ul.squares > li:nth-child(1n-7)").removeClass("select");
$(this).addClass("select");
e.preventDefault();
//alert("i am a li");
});

// just for nested <li>
$(document).on("click","ul.nested > li", function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
$("ul.nested > li").removeClass("select_blue");
$(this).addClass("select_blue");
e.preventDefault();
alert("i am a nested li");
});
```

**More comments and demo on jsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/H5ZdE/31/

Answer (score 2):

```
// why does this first condition cause both li's to be green?
$("li:has(ul)").css('background','Green');
```

The above line does NOT cause both `li` to be green. It causes the first parent `li` only to be green. However, because the child `li` (which does not contain a `ul`) does not have a background color of its own, it appears to be green because it is inheriting its parent's background color.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML and Javascript you've written conflict. The second `<li>` is nested inside the first, and because it's styled background green, all child elements are inside that `<li>` background.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/H5ZdE/4/

The Javascript is not actually styling that second `<li>` to background green. It's simply inside the `<li>` whose background *is* green.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting an `li` that has a nested `ul` use

`$('li ul').parent()`
(this will return the parent `li` tags of the selected `ul` tags. You can use `li>ul` as well)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("li:has(ul)").css('background', 'green')
$('li ul').css('background', 'red')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H5ZdE/6/